# Can generic types be used as the "type" of a composite component's attribute tag?

Tags: java, generics, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

It looks to me like composite components' attributes don't allow generic types. Here's a simple test case:

```
<cc:attribute name="stringList" type="java.util.List&lt;java.lang.String&gt;" />
```

The error I get is,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

(If I replace the &lt; and &gt; with < and >, I get a error because that's not valid XHTML.)

I know that the generic part of the type will be erased at runtime, but I was hoping to use generics here just for clarity of reading the code. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113603/jsf2-limiting-ccattribute-to-a-given-object-type-within-a-list

Comment: I don't know what are doing exactly, but maybe java.lang.String and not java.util.String?

Comment: @khachik Yup, had the wrong package for String (fixed in post). Still get the same exception, though. I have resigned myself to the fact that it is currently impossible to do what I was trying to do.

Comment: I don't know about JSF, but it's generally useful to use a meaningful type rather than "a sequence of some text".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no man its not possible

Comment: Wow. This gotta be the shortest correct answer I've seen on SO. Brevity is a gift :)

Comment: back in the day, answers could be shorter than 30 chars long. good old days :)