# How to enforce the type of a cc:attribute in a JSF composite component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I don't seem to find any clear reference which effect the `type` attribute has on `cc:attribute` in JSF 2.2 composite components. I'd like to make sure that the type of a passed EL expression matches `type` and throw an exception otherwise. Afaik the specification of `type` should do that because otherwise I see no point in having the attribute, but I'm aware that there's some (at first side) odd conversions in JSF, e.g. between `null` and `""`, so that an exception might not be thrown.

If no exception is thrown what would be the most elegant way to throw an exception at runtime (or at build time if possible)?

[JSF2: limiting cc:attribute to a given object type within a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113603/jsf2-limiting-ccattribute-to-a-given-object-type-within-a-list) explains the issue for checking the generic type of a list, but the solution (to check the type with `attributeValue.class.name` which seems quite hacky) mustn't necessarily be necessary for this case there I want to check/assert the raw type.

I'm also interested in a solution for JSF 2.3.

Comment: Did you implement some test to be sure no exception is thrown? Which code? Which JSF impls did you use for testing? Share it!

Comment: And did you try giving the cc a backing and do checking there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602953/binding-a-managed-bean-instance-to-composite-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Primefaces 5.0 and 6.2 check the type in the following situation:

Composite component:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="theValue"
                type="java.util.List"
                required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        #{cc.attrs.theValue.add("abc")}
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean0 implements Serializable {
    private Set<String> property0 = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<String> getProperty0() {
        return property0;
    }

    public void setProperty0(Set<String> property0) {
        this.property0 = property0;
    }
}
```

`index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:typesafety="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/typesafety">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <typesafety:comp theValue="#{backingBean0.property0}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'll edit the question if I encounter the situation again which caused me to doubt that there's a check.